# android error : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2, Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i am a beginner student of android basics course and i was making an recommend lecture app but when i run it with android emulator on android studio it is giving the following log error as well as showing "unfortunately has stopped" on my device.

Hello, I'm developing an Android app with Kotlin. I would like to get the image url from retrofit2 and display the poster image in the recycler view on the main screen. However, there is an error as above, so could you help me?

error message :

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.looc, PID: 19848
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.looc:layout/item_poster: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.looc:layout/item_poster: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.looc:layout/item_poster: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:663)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at com.example.looc.view.RecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.kt:125)
        at com.example.looc.view.RecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.kt:105)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:761)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3676)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2739)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2179)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8787)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1037)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:780)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 35: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f03036b a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:998)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:982)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5884)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:702)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:254)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:250)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:246)
            ... 67 more
```

item_poster.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:targetApi="m"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/poster_image"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@drawable/poster_bg" />


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/main_background_color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">




    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_first"
        android:name="com.example.looc.view.FeedFragment"/>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recommend_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_poster" />



    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.looc.view

import RetrofitInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.looc.R
import com.example.looc.data.LectureDetailItem
import com.example.looc.server.RetrofitClient
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import java.io.IOException
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//       val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.test_image)
//       Glide.with(this).load("https://contents.kyobobook.co.kr/sih/fit-in/458x0/pdt/9791190977852.jpg").into(imageView)

        val recommendRecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recommend_recycler_view)
        val recommendLectureList = mutableListOf<String>()


        val retrofit = RetrofitClient.retrofit
        retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface::class.java).getLectures().enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<LectureDetailItem>>{
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ArrayList<LectureDetailItem>>,
                response: Response<ArrayList<LectureDetailItem>>
            ) {
                if(response.isSuccessful){

                    val lecturePoster = response.body()
                    recommendLectureList.add("http://172.16.0.94:5000/static/images/"+lecturePoster!!.get(0).image)
                    recommendRecyclerView.adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(recommendLectureList, LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext))

                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<LectureDetailItem>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("testt", "메인화면 이미지 불러오기 실패")
            }
        })
        
    }
}

class RecyclerViewAdapter(
    var lectureList : List<String>,
    var inflater: LayoutInflater
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        //inner class
        val lectureImage : ImageView
        val context = itemView.context
        init {
            lectureImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.poster_image)
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context, DetailedPageActivity::class.java)
                intent.run { context.startActivity(this) }
            }
        }

   }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_poster, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
//        Log.d("testt", lectureList.get(0))
//        holder.lectureImage.setImageBitmap(loadImage(lectureList.get(position)))

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return  1
    }


    fun loadImage(imageUrl: String): Bitmap? {
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        val connection: HttpURLConnection?

        try {
            val url = URL(imageUrl)
            connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

            connection.requestMethod = "GET" // request 방식 설정
            connection.connectTimeout = 10000 // 10초의 타임아웃
            connection.doOutput = true // OutPutStream으로 데이터를 넘겨주겠다고 설정
            connection.doInput = true // InputStream으로 데이터를 읽겠다는 설정
            connection.useCaches = true // 캐싱 여부
            connection.connect()
            val resCode = connection.responseCode 
            if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                val input = connection.inputStream
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input) 
                connection.disconnect()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return bitmap
    }
}
```

I saw the 2nd line of item_poster.xml and it doesn't look like a problem.